# Optimal way to retrieve data from child component to parent when the action is initiated by the parent

Tags: reactjs, performance

I'm aware of passing data from child to parent using callbacks.
But my question is: best way to initiate the callback triggering from the parent?. Passing a boolean prop to turn on the trigger seems non optimal if it needs to be turned off before turned on again if data needs to be retrieved multiple times, right?
is there a better approach?

Let's say moving state up to the parent is not viable,  maybe it is a third party component or any other valid reason that don't allow it.

```
    //pseudo code showing attempt to initiate the callback invocation from parent, by pasing a prop to trigger the callback
    function Parent() {
       const postProcessData = (data:any)=>{
          console.debug(data)
       }
       // used to control when the callback will be invoked on the child side
       const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState<boolean>(false)

       return (<Child onReturnData={postProcessData} invokeCallback={trigger} />)
    }

    function Child({onReturnData:()=>any, trigger: boolean}) {
       //will be called only if trigger changes 
       useEffect(()=>{  
          if(trigger) 
             onReturnData(/*some calculated stuff*/)
       },[trigger])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to trigger some function in the child component from the parent component the proper way, check out [useImperativeHandle](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) hook.

To summarize what the hook does, you can pass a ref from the parent to the child component and add additional properties to the ref using the useImperativeHandle. Now you can use these properties in your parent by accessing the ref object.